# undefined local variable or method 'gallery'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Okay, so I'm rebuilding an old photo gallery management app that I built a few years back in ROR 1 and running in to a few coding difficulties, since I'm rusty and apparently things have changed. My first question is I'm getting an undefined local variable or method 'gallery' error when trying to call a page. What I'm confused about is that I have the method defined in the 'gallery' controller but I'm wondering if I'm completely missing something. Here are some relevant code snippets, first is my index.html.erb page:

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>

<div>
<%= image_tag(photo.thumb_url) %>
<%= link_to 'Show', gallery %><br/>

</div>
<% end %>
<p><%= will_paginate @photos %></p>
```

my gallery controller:

```
class GalleryController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize
  # GET /gallery
  # GET /gallery.xml
  def index
    @photos = Photo.all
    @photos = Photo.paginate :page=>params[:page], :order=>'date desc',
    :per_page => 2

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @gallery }
    end
  end

  # GET /gallery/1
  # GET /gallery/1.xml

  def show
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @photo }
    end
  end
end
```

And my error:

```
undefined local variable or method `gallery' for #<#<Class:0x111127b38>:0x1112d5700>
```

I should clarify that "Photos" is the admin section which requires login and contains all of the fields/database/record data. I have no problem using the following line:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', photo %><br/>
```

Which brings up the correct record and viewing page, but in the admin section of the site (which requires login). Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: the error says it all. 

    <div>
    <%= image_tag(photo.thumb_url) %>
    <%= link_to 'Show', gallery %><br/>

what is gallery's value here?

Comment: I didn't give a good look at your code I guess. All you need to do is `<%= link_to 'Show', photo %><br/>`. It will redirect to gallery#show action as photo is an instance of Gallery Model :)  You can use `gallery_path` too but still you need to pass `photo` as parameter to it.

Comment: I've tried that and it works. However, I believe that is using the "show" action of my PhotoController, which handles the admin portion of my site. In other words, if I do that it requires a login. Once logged in, it correctly accesses the show.html.erb file, but the one located in the admin (Photo) portion of the app. That is what is so confusing, it works perfectly when I use that action, but just doesn't work when I use the exact same code in the GalleryController (which is suppose to act as the front end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your link_to method with something like: `<%= link_to 'Show', :controller => "photos", :action => :your_method, :params1 => gallery %>`.

Then in your PhotoController you can use: `@my_gallery = params[:params1]` to access your gallery item.

Some documentation on routes:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere do I see you defining the variable `gallery`, and this is what your error message is telling you: `gallery` is undefined in your view.

---

Update RE your comments:

Just because you want the photo to go to the gallery controller doesn't mean you can just type "gallery" and expect results. This is a programming langauge, where words have meanings, and all you're doing is referencing an undefined variable. This, and nothing like this, has ever worked in any version of Rails.

If you want to route your photo to the Gallery controller, you can use the automagically generated `_path` helpers; specifically, `gallery_path`, which accepts an argument for the id of the "gallery" (really a photo) to show:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', gallery_path(photo.id) %><br/>
```

Comment: I'm not intending on using gallery as a variable, I want to call the show function in gallery_controller. In rails 1, I used to achieve this by using: `code`<%= link_to(image_tag(photo.thumb_url, :size => "175x131", :border => 0, :alt => photo.event_name), :action => 'show', :id => photo) %>`code`

Comment: That's fine, but `<%= link_to 'Show', gallery %><br/>` references a variable called "gallery" which clearly doesn't exist.

Comment: @CorneliusQualley I think may be you want to put `<%= link_to 'Show', photo %><br/>` instead. :)

Comment: And that works, but it uses the action from my PhotoController rather than my GalleryController. It will pull the show.html.erb file from my Views > Photos rather than using the show.html.erb file from my Views > Gallery. My PhotoController handles the admin portion of the site, the GalleryController is supposed to handle the front end (user portion).

Comment: @meagar, I understand that words have meaning in every programming language, my problem is that in ROR there are so many functions that are performed "automagically" making understanding the language almost more confusing, there are shortcuts which would never work in other languages. I'm much more used to PHP. In any case, `<%= link_to 'Show', gallery_path(photo.id) %><br/>` results in yet another error: `private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass`